# How to get the maximum in each bin of a 2D histogram in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy, in particular the histrogram2d function.
I am binning a 3D spatial distribution of points (arrays `x`,`y` and `z`) with a 2d histogram. For each point I have an associated density field `d`.

If I do something like that

```
import numpy as np
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=200,weights=d)
```

The histogram `H` represent the sum of the density along the line-of-sight (in this case in the z-axis). This is pretty fast and easy considering that I'm working with very big arrays.

Now I want to go further and instead of plotting the sum of the density filed along the line-of-sight I would like to get the maximum of the density in each 2D bin. 
I coded the possible solution:

```
from numpy import *
x=array([0.5,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.25,0.35,0.6,0.1,0.22,0.7,0.45,0.57,0.65])
y=array([0.5,0.5,0.28,0.18,0.85,0.9,0.44,0.7,0.1,0.22,0.7,0.45,0.54,0.65])
d=array([1,1,2,2,3,5,6,8,7,9,6,10,5,7])

bins=linspace(0,1,64)

idx=digitize(x,bins) 
idy=digitize(y,bins) 

img2=zeros((len(bins),len(bins)))

for i in arange(0,len(d)):
  dummy=idx[i]
  dummy2=idy[i]
  img2[dummy][dummy2]=max(d[i],img2[dummy][dummy2])
```

However the loop in the last lines might be really slow for a huge dataset. Any idea on how I can make it faster?

Comment: May be will you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750894/numpy-histogram-how-to-take-the-maximum-value-in-each-bin

Comment: thanks, that was a question that I actually asked a while ago but it was about 1D array. I've just edited the question to get the maximum along the los as I wanted but it might be quite slow, especially the last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, sorry I don't have time to write up the code right now:

1. Use `numpy.ravel_multi_index` to turn the 2d problem into a 1d problem.
2. Take a look at the implementation of `numpy.unique`, you want to do something like that to get unique bin values, but you want to do it in such a way so that it also gives you the min/max of `d` at the same time. `numpy.lexsort` might also help here.
3. To move back into 2d space it should be as simple as `img2.flat[uniq_1d_bin_value] = bin_max`

I hope that's enough to get you started. If you have trouble, you can post your code and let us know where you got stuck and maybe I, or someone else, can help put you on the right path again.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments. However, I can't use `ravel_multi_index` because my numpy version it's not updated. But I would like to understand the logic of your answer. It's still possible assigning an index to every cell so as to convert the problem from 2D to 1D but then the problem still remains in getting the maximum in each bin. I will post the preliminary code I wrote very soon.

Comment: `ravel_multi_index` is a pretty straightforward function, you can recreate it yourself if you're using an older version of numpy. Getting the max in every bin is very similar to the problem of getting a unique set of bins. Take a look at the implementation of numpy.unique and see if you can write something similar that gives you a unique set of bins and the max in each bin at the same time.